# How to change class of the element parent in jQuery tabs script?

Tags: jquery

I use code from this tutorial: jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs.

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='tab1'>
    <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
</div>
<div id='tab2'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
</div>
<div id='tab3'>
    <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I want to modify this script to add/remove class 'active' to parent `li` element of `a`. I tried to replace `$active.addClass('active');` with `$active.parent('li').addClass('active');`, but behavior of resulted code is not good.

Comment: Should work fine, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @billyonecan When I click on tabs the first one still have active class unless I click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `active` class from the previously clicked element:

```
// Make the old tab inactive.
$active.parent('li').removeClass('active');
```

You also need to add the `active` to the first `list` element as well:

```
// If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
$active.parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several places you need to target the parent li:

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.parent('li').addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.parent('li').not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.parent('li').removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.parent('li').addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

I've thrown together a JSFiddle that appears to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kGTX/